# Import error: No module named _sysconfigdata

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, pyinstaller, importerror

Anaconda python 2.7.14 scripts that import either matplotlib or scipy and are compiled with pyinstaller 3.3 fail with identical errors: 
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata [54885] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres.

Those scripts execute perfectly in the python envirnnment, e.g. python myscript.py.  When the executable is run I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1040, in <module>
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1043, in Environment
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 272, in get_supported_platform
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 478, in get_build_platform
  File "sysconfig.py", line 617, in get_platform
  File "sysconfig.py", line 481, in get_config_vars
  File "sysconfig.py", line 364, in _init_posix
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata
[54885] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3198.